# How can i pin a map by runtime.Pinner?

Tags: go, runtime, cgo

The memory for param comes from the Mmap, so assigning a member of param directly will cause problems.

````golang
func InitNullMap(param *tree.ExternParam, ctx CompilerContext) error {
    m := make(map[string][]string)
    param.NullMap = m

// write of unpinned Go pointer 0x1400cac1ce0 to non-Go memory 0x10ed44110
// fatal error: unpinned Go pointer stored into non-Go memory
```go

I’ve used runtime.Pinner successfully with other common datatypes, such as structures or strings, but I’ve found that I can’t handle map.

```go
func InitNullMap(param *tree.ExternParam, ctx CompilerContext) error {
    m := make(map[string][]string)
    buf := ctx.GetBuffer()
    buf.Pin(m) // bin.Pin(&m) also won't work
    param.NullMap = m

// what buf is and what buf.Pin do
func New() *Buffer {
    b := new(Buffer)
    b.pinner = new(runtime.Pinner)
    b.pinner.Pin(b)
    return b
}

func (b *Buffer) Pin(os ...any) {
    for _, o := range os {
        b.pinner.Pin(o)
    }
}
````

There are no examples in go/src/runtime/pinner_test.go, and I haven’t found any useful discussions, can anyone help ?

I've looked into the pinner_test.go, checked the documentation for go

Comment: When you say `won't work` what do you mean? Is it a compile-time issue or a runtime issue? AFAIK it's not a good idea to pin Go maps because internally, it contains pointers as well, which you would have to recursively pin. A post was made about how the docs could reflect this nuance so users of the new API are aware of these things. See here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/62380